# TensorFlow / Keras Error : dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I wrote a program using Keras. When I run the program it crashes with an error as seen below:

```
2021-02-23 18:50:50.  : W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2021-02-23 18:50:50.  : I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/Sofia/main.py", line 26, in <module>
    X = dataset[:,0:8]
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3024, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 75, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), slice(0, 8, None))' is an invalid key
```

Here is my code:

```
# Develop Neural Network with Keras

# Load Libraries
# first neural network with keras tutorial
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy
from pandas import read_csv
# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)
# Load Data
dataset = read_csv('pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv', delimiter=',')
# split into input (X) and output (y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:8]
y = dataset[:,8]
# Define Keras Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
# Compile Keras Model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit Keras Model
model.fit(X, y, epochs=150, batch_size=10)
# Evaluate Keras
_, accuracy = model.evaluate(X, y)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))
```

How would I go about fixing this error?

Comment: Your code does not reproduce the error. See how to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't installed the NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit, OR your paths are not configured correctly OR your tensorflow installation version requires a different cuda version. You can try using tensorflow CPU if you don't want or can't set up your GPU (e.g. because you don't have on).